# How to communicate between sibling components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to transfer props from one sibling to another, please?

In main app I have only 2 siblings:

**Input:**

```
import React from "react";

const Input = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="name">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="TheDareback" />
      <label htmlFor="job">Job Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="job" placeholder="Frontend Developer" />
    </>
  );
};

export default inputDetails;
```

**Preview:**

```
import React from "react";

const Preview = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>{/* here I need a Full Name from the input */}</th>
            <th>{/* here I need a Job Title from the input*/}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default Preview;
```

I tried to add useEffect to Preview to read the value of each input.

for example

```
  const name = document.querySelector("#name");
  const [inputName, setInputName] = useState("TheDareback");

  useEffect(() => (name.value ? setInputName(name.value) : null));
```

But I'm still getting an error:

`Preview.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`

Is it possible to run useEffect only during the second rendering? Alternatively, is there another option than to move the props directly from Input.js where would I create a handler for each onChange in input?

Thank you very much for heading in the right direction.

Comment: Short answer: Via the parent (or other ancestor). (Don't have time to post an actual answer.)

Comment: I also tried it via App.js, but the problem is that I get the same error. Unable to read null properties.

Comment: Agree with @T.J.Crowder, keeping the props on the parent level is the way to go. Using refs is not recommended (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the state in the `App` component and give setter to `Input` and `state` to `Preview` component.

#### App.js

```
import Input from "./Input";
import Preview from "./Preview";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ name: "", job: "" });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input setState={setState} />
      <Preview state={state} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Input.js

```
import React from "react";

const Input = ({ setState }) => {
  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="name">Full Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="name"
        placeholder="TheDareback"
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
      <label htmlFor="job">Job Title</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="job"
        placeholder="Frontend Developer"
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

#### Preview.js

```
import React from "react";

const Preview = ({ state: { name, job } }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>{name}</th>
            <th>{job}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default Preview;
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-star-mlmx5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You can provide your runnable examples **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Remember that some sites are blocked for some users.

Comment: A bit off-topic but still related. If the input component serves the parameters that are then used in a request to an API, the outcome of which results in data to be rendered in the preview component - where would the fetching of the data be located? In the holding parent, in the previewer or in a separate, dedicated, non-visual component? Now, I put my API call in the parent but I sense there's a better approach to that, making the preview component dumb.

Answer (score 2):

You need some sort of a container component (or App.js for example), you can have an input state there, and an inputHandler function to pass to the Input component and put it with an onChange for example.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function Container() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    name: '',
    job: ''
  })

  const inputHandler = (e, type) => {
    setInput(prevState => ({...prevState, [type]: e.target.value}))
  }
  return (
    <>
    <Input onInputChange={inputHandler} />
    <Preview input={input} />
    </>
  );
}
```

**Input:**

```
const Input = ({onInputChange}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="name">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="TheDareback" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e, 'name')} />
      <label htmlFor="job">Job Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="job" placeholder="Frontend Developer" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e, 'job')} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

**Preview:**

```
const Preview = ({input}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>{input.name}</th>
            <th>{input.job}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default Preview;
```

Comment: Thank you @ben, I would never have thought of such a solution. Anyway, it's effective :) Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck.